# MYSQL Join From Two Tables

Tags: mysql

I am not sure what I am missing but I know it should not be this hard. I have two tables. First table lists all the possible jobs for a site. The second table has when a job was completed at a site. I want a query where by I get all the possible jobs and join in the data from the seconds table should there be some. Site that have not completed the job would have a NULL value.

**Example:**

*Table 1:*
ID
name
decsription

*Table 2:*
ID
siteID
status
jobID

```
SELECT table1.* , table2.*
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.jobID
WHERE siteID = 12
```

This only returns jobs that have been completed and not all jobs completed and uncompleted.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should drop then where statement (when the row in second table is emty it doesn't meet the condition siteID=12) or change it (add "OR siteID is NULL" ) if you want this specific site or null

Answer (score 0):

A simple change should do, just change the order of the values on the `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT table1.* , table2.* 
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table2.jobID = table1.id
WHERE siteID = 12 OR siteID IS NULL
```

And keep in mind the siteID will be `NULL` when there are no results, so change your `WHERE` as well.

Comment: I kept putting in siteID = null not siteID is null. What is the difference?

Comment: According to [MySQL's documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html): "You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL. Because the result of any arithmetic comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons."